# Can't update and can't open the manager

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 10.04(Gnome) and since the last update, I no longer can update or open the manager and many other programs. On the console when I try to update it says http://ppa.launchpad.net/hakermania/format-junkie/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

It also appears that I have 904 files outdated. I have tried so many commands, but any one works duo this error. Can some one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system (10.04) is very out of date and no longer in support - for example, the hakermania launchpad supports only precise, not lucid.  You will probably need to update to 12.04 LTS or 14.04.  There is a good set of instructions for upgrading at [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm trying a lot of commands, but no one works. By the way I instaled the last version but when I run it appears on the screen "Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /." then I skip and then appears "The disk drive for /tmp is not ready or not present" then I skik and appears the black screan with login and pass. I write and shows a lot of commands but then nothing happen. Doesn't run more. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: It sound like your hard drive is failing and needs to be replaced.